# "import module as m" from strings in python

Tags: python, python-import

if I supply `("pandas", "pd")`, is it possible to obtain `import pandas as pd` programatically?

I do know that I can do:

```
import importlib
pd = importlib.import_module('pandas')
```

But, can I supply the `pd` somehow as a string as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, yes, and in more than way:

```
locals()['pd'] = importlib.import_module('pandas')
```

Of course, it rather bad practice.

Comment: OK. I am actually trying to get ipython to import some modules upon startup if they exist.

Comment: Why don't you just use `try…except` to handle the case of missing module?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
name = 'pd'
exec(f'import pandas as {name}')
```